# How to get Specific value in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data in firebase is as follows:

[image: Check Firebase Data Image]

Structure shown in Json format:

```
{
  "Admin" : {
    "-Kp0mScwQLk0CHarwIUj" : {
      "Account Type" : "Admin",
      "Email Address" : "admin01@dsu.edu.pk",
      "Name" : "Ali Bukhari"
    },
    "-Kp0nC9pVefh65_SFcpu" : {
      "Account Type" : "Admin",
      "Email Address" : "a@test.com",
      "Name" : "Admin"
    }
  },
  "Company" : {
    "-Kp0eMor6BovZHTUZSKR" : {
      "Account Type" : "Company",
      "Company Name" : "SI Labs",
      "Email Address" : "silabs@dsu.edu.pk",
      "Industry" : "IT",
      "No of Employees" : "25",
      "Year Founded" : "2014"
    },
    "-Kp0fgQs7iE6AbIho7Eo" : {
      "Account Type" : "Company",
      "Company Name" : "Panacloud",
      "Email Address" : "panacloud@gmail.com",
      "Industry" : "IT",
      "No of Employees" : "100",
      "Year Founded" : "2014"
    }
 }
}
```

I am taking Email Address input from user through EditText.
And I want to find "Account Type" of the email address which is provided by user.
E.g: User Input "silabs@dsu.edu.pk", so I want to toast its "Account type" i.e Company in this example.

```
private EditText mEmailAuthen = (EditText).findViewById(R.id.emailAuthen);
String mEmail = mEmailAuthen.getText().toString();

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("Email Address").equalTo(mEmail);
```

I tried this, but not sure what to do further.

Comment: If the email is unique key, why don't you use that in place of `-Kp0...`?

Comment: You need to restructure your table as @cricket_007 suggested.

Comment: @cricket_007 & Reaz Murshed : Let's assume if email is not a unique key, so can't I get value without restructuring my table?

Comment: You could, but you need to iterate over each child by their ID value in order to search for their corresponding email key

Comment: @cricket_007 so please help me for in writing logic for this structure. Because I have to use similar thing with "Year Founded" in different part of application using same data. So I can't restructure my data for "Email Address".